# How can I call a JavaScript function that is a module with wasm-bindgen?

Tags: rust, webassembly, wasm-bindgen

I'm trying to use the Web3 JavaScript library from Rust and I'm stuck. The standard usage of the library starts with:

```js
// In Node.js use: const Web3 = require('web3');

let web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8545");
```

The module you're supposed to import is a constructor, that also has some other properties. My Rust code that's supposed to bind this API looks like this:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen(module = "web3")]
extern "C" {
    type Web3;

    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
    fn new(_: &Provider) -> Web3;

    type Provider;

    static givenProvider: Provider;
}
```

Which ends up outputting `import { Web3, givenProvider } from 'web3';` and trying to run `new Web3(...)` which fails. It should be doing something like `import * as Web3 from 'web3';`, running `new Web3(...)` and referencing `Web3.givenProvider`.

How can I get wasm-bindgen to output code like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT**: The original answer is wrong. You *can* import things defined like that using `wasm-bindgen`, and they *are* legal ES6. Or at least the same concept is available in ES6 modules. They call them [default exports/imports](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export). It's a bit awkward, but the way to import them is to use `js_name = "default"`. Like so:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen(module = "web3")]
extern "C" {
    #[wasm_bindgen(js_name = "default")]
    type Web3;

    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor, js_class = "default")]
    fn new(_: &Provider) -> Web3;

    #[wasm_bindgen(static_method_of = Web3, getter, js_class = "default")]
    fn givenProvider() -> Provider;

    type Provider;
}
```

You need the `js_class` parameter on methods, it doesn't remember that `Web3`'s `js_name` is `default`.

---

**Old, wrong answer**:

The reason you can't get `wasm-bindgen` to generate code like that is because it's not legal ES6. ECMAScript modules use named exports for everything. Web3 is actually a CommonJS module, and those *do* support having a single anonymous export.

The reason it *almost* works is because I was using webpack, and webpack lets you import CommonJS modules using ES6 syntax, even though the semantics are slightly different.

The solution is to make a little shim, exporting the CommonJS module from an ES6 module:

```js
export let Web3 = require('web3');
```

Then this binding will work:

```rust
#[wasm_bindgen(module = "/src/web3-wrapper.js")]
extern "C" {
    type Web3;

    #[wasm_bindgen(constructor)]
    fn new(_: &Provider) -> Web3;

    #[wasm_bindgen(static_method_of = Web3, getter)]
    fn givenProvider() -> Provider;

    type Provider;
}
```